# Flat File as Input - MySQL Best Practice

Tags: mysql, csv, relational-database, normalization

I receive a flat file (CSV) each day, the contents of which gets imported into my database (rather than data entry through a web form, POS or the like). There are 40 fields in a record and I'm up to 600,000 unique records.

Up until now, I haven't seen the need to make this a relational database though there certainly is some normalization that would make it more efficient; repeating products, stores, customers, resellers, etc.

If I was starting this from the beginning and incrementally inputting the data somehow, I'd know how to do all that (every resource I've gone through covers it that way but none cover it when you have a large volume of data already and need to make it relational). And with the CVS's coming in each day I'm not quite sure how to import the data once the database is set up. If I were to split those 40 fields into say 5 tables would I then have to split that daily file the same way and import them one at a time?  Would foreign keys update that way?

If someone could push me in the right direction I'll go do more digging on my own.

If you were faced with the same project, how would you create such a database and perform the daily updates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your database structure independently of what you have right now (CSV structure and data). E.g. organize your tables to fit your future needs, think and define the relations between them good, apply proper indexes.

As the second step - unavoidable in my opinion, write a little program in the programming language of your own. It should be able to

- mainly read records/lines from a (CSV) file,
- validate/sanitize the fetched data
- import/save the data in the correspondent database tables, as needed. By "as needed", I mean, that, in time, can appear a multitude of factors which could unexpectedly influence your first db-structural decisions. For example, the need for some temporal tables. Also, you should benefit from the advantages given to you by the triggers and stored procedures.
- properly handle the errors and exceptions raised along the importing process. For example, due to eventual "duplicate key" issues - because data in files can be error-prone, some records could not be imported in a certain day. That doesn't mean that the import should break. Read a record, try to save it. If a problem appears, handle it (copy the line in another file, or save it in a special table, for a later editing/revision and re-import) and let the program follow its course with the next records.
- properly log all (main) operations and maintain a counter of the read and of the problematic records.
- automatically copy each daily file - after import - in a backup directory, until its not needed anymore.
- eventually signalize you per email about the status of the operations.

The third step would be to find a solution to automatize the whole cycle. For example, to find a tasks/cron-jobs manager to start your program daily, once or even twice a day, without you having to make this manually.

Regarding of splitting the file into different files, based on your ddatabase structure: it wouldn't be necessary, e.g. it would be a redundant step, since your program should manage to read the file and handle the data import correspondingly.

As of the type of the program: it should be a web solution, so that you can access and modify it any time you need.

Good luck.

Comment: Great outline and exactly the direction I was looking for. Thanks aendeerei!